# How to access private members of a nested class?

Tags: c++

**A.hpp**

```
class A
{
  public:
  class B
  {
    int x;
  public:
    B(int f);
  };
  void alpha(B *random);
};
```

**A.cpp**

```
void A::alpha(A::B *random)
{  
  // access x here, how to do it?
}
```

The private variable is getting set at some place and I want to access that value in this `alpha` function. How can I access `x` inside `alpha()`?

EDIT: 2nd Question:
**A.hpp**

```
class A
{
  public:
  class B
  {
    int x;
  public:
    B(int f);
  };
  virtual void alpha(B *random) = 0;
};
```

**C.hpp**

```
class C : public A
{
  public:
  virtual void alpha(B *random);
};
```

**C.cpp**

```
void C::alpha(A:B *random)
{  
  // access x here, how to do it? 
}
```

Comment: If `B` is a private nested class of `A`, you could just make its members public. They'd be accessible to `A` and not anything else.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. Class B is public but inside that "int x" is private @NathanPierson

Answer (score 4):

You can make class `A` a "friend" of class `B` which allows `A` to access private members of `B`

combining your files for ease of compilation:

```cpp
class A
{
  public:
  class B
  {
    friend class A;  // *** HERE ***
    int x;
  public:
    B(int f);
  };
  void alpha(B *random);
};



void A::alpha(B *random)
{
    int x = random->x;
}

int main() {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a similar 2nd question. I have added it as an edit in my question. Do I need to add the friend in C.hpp or A.hpp then?

Comment: @galaxy2096 - The header file you need to edit is the one that contains the definition of `B` (in your case A.hpp). Specifically, class `B` needs to declare every other class that needs access to `B`s private members as a `friend`. So if members of `A` needs access (e.g. `A::alpha()` and other members of `A`) then `A` needs to be a `friend` whereas if members of `C` need access, then `C` needs to be a friend.  Friendship of classes is not inherited - declaring `A` as a `friend` does not cause `C` to be a `friend` and, conversely,  declaring `C` as a `friend` does not cause `A` to be a `friend`

Comment: Change the declaration of `C::alpha()` from `void alpha(B *)` to `void alpha(A::B *)`.   Optionally, using C++11 and later, use `override` in the definition of `C`  (i.e.  doing `void alpha(B *) override` will cause the compiler to tell you that `C::alpha()` is not overriding `A::alpha()` but `void alpha(A::B *) override` will work.

Comment: @Peter Yes I already had that before. I forgot to add it in the question. But when I try to add "friend class C" below "friend class A" , it throws an error saying it does not know class C

Comment: A second question should be a new question, not tacked onto this one

Comment: Then either place a declaration of `class C` (outside any class) before the definition of `B` or change the friend declaration to `friend class ::C`  (or both).   You need to remember that every class you are declaring/defining is in a scope, and that any declarations (e.g. as friends) or usage need to be properly (unambiguously) qualified.   If the compiler believes it is in a different scope than you do, the compiler wins.

Answer (score 1):

A class can access another class's `private` members if it's a `friend` of that other class, like in this example:

```
class A {
 public:
  class B {
    friend class A;
    int x;

   public:
    B(int f);
  };
  void alpha(B *random) { random->x = 10; }
};
```